# Good academic books on temperament theory?

Tags: reference-request, personality

I'm looking for a few books that provide an academic or at least "well-researched" perspective on temperament theory.  This could include material on the OCEAN model, or other research into the psychology of human personality and temperament.

Textbooks are fine; any good books you know of would be appreciated.